# Android's Vibrator Service intensity pattern sticks for system's soft keys after calling vibrate() method

Tags: android, vibration

I am using the Android's VIBRATOR_SERVICE to make my device vibrate on a finite, non-repeating event with a custom, non repeating pattern like this:

```
((Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE))
                .vibrate(Constants.VIBRATION_DELETE_CHAT, 1);
```

This works alright for the desired event. However, once the device has vibrated as expected, as long as the app isn't stopped (by manually force stopping it or waiting for the system to stop it) the device's soft keys vibrate in the same high-intensity pattern I originally specified for my event.

Do I need to set system's vibration defaults once I've set my own custom one shot vibration or why are the soft keys being affected by this line of code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `Vibrator.vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat)` should not effect the systems vibration defaults.

Check the value of the `int repeat` parameter you are passing is correct. This parameter is an index into the vibration pattern you have provided. As you are passing 1 as this parameter you will need to manually call `Vibrator.cancel()` to stop the repeating. Change this parameter to -1 to prevent it from repeating.

Also, if this index is outside the bounds of the size of the vibration pattern array it may cause issues.